# Lunch scrapy from crontab using python script

Tags: python, cron, scrapy, raspberry-pi

I set crontab on my raspberry pi to schedule scrapy to run periodically:

```
43 8 * * * python3 /mnt/uhdd/scripts/folder/runscript.py &
```

This is how the script looks like

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen
import pickle

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with open('/mnt/uhdd/scripts/folder/worked','wb') as f:
        pickle.dump('worked',f)
        
    os.chdir('/mnt/uhdd/scripts/folder/')
    onvista = Popen(['scrapy', 'crawl', 'spider'], close_fds=True)
```

If a start the script manually, it works fine without any error but if it starts from crontab only the pickle dump worked but not the Popen.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: things in crontab are executed with a specific user and environment which may differ from your terminal. Environment variables are often not defined in crontab. The easiest way to debug is to print env variables from a crontab script a see what's different from a terminal.

Comment: Solution found. I had to put the entire scrapy path even in the python script: onvista = Popen(['/usr/local/bin/scrapy', 'crawl', 'somespide'])